# Bottom margin not working when placing a photo

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set an image on my page to have a top margin of 40px, a bottom margin of 40px and a left margin of 25%, but the bottom margin is not working. Here is my HTML code:

```
<body>
<img src="image.jpg" id="photo">
</body>
```

And my CSS code:

```
#photo {
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
bottom: 40px;
left: 25%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
}
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: You haven't set bottom margin. You've set bottom position. Try `margin-bottom: 40px;`

Comment: left, right, top, bottom are css properties to position the element when having position absolute. Those are not margins as Onimusha told

Comment: Yes, the margin will not work if you have an absolute position. to apply margin you should have position as a relative

Comment: #photo {
  margin: 40px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
.center-div {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
  <div class="center-div">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1453728013993-6d66e9c9123a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8dmlld3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&w=1000&q=80" id="photo">
  </div>